# Dividing range of numbers by a variable in VBA (Excel)

Tags: vba, vbscript, excel

I have the following code inside a loop:

```
Range("N" & i + 1).Formula = "=L" & (i + 1) / resp2
```

The code above is suppose to take Column `L` and divide by an integer, here it is called `resp2`. After dividing the number by `resp2` put it in Coulmn `N`.

I can't seem to figure out the syntax because it keeps giving me an error or wrong numbers when I try to run the macro.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: More context for that line of code would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Range("N" & i + 1).Formula = "=L" & (i + 1) & "/" & resp2
```

So if the value of `i = 2` and the value of `resp2 = 5` the `N3` Cell will have `=L3/5`

Comment: Yup that was it! Thanks a lot. I'm fairly new to using VB so wasn't sure about the & sign. Again thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Gr8 :) I remember my early days with VB ;)

Comment: While Siddharth's answer is 100% correct, it seems to me this could be solved without VBA if he just wants column N to have values equal to Column L divided by some constant (could locate in a cell for easy changing)

Comment: @RossLarson I generally agree as well, however, as I noted in a comment on the question, there is some context missing which would help determine if you are correct. (For example, if only SOME cells in a column/range should have this calculation applied -- though now that I say this, a formula could still probably cover that as well...)